# Gnome-shell ugly icons

Tags: gnome, alacarte

I have problem with running python and java apps on gnome-shell.

When I launch it via the overview, it works nice. But if I try to launch it through the terminal, an ugly icon (not defined by alacarte) shows up:

[image]

```
petr@sova:~$ ps -ef | grep lightread
petr      5021  3512 19 09:29 pts/0    00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /home/petr/scripts/bin/lightread
petr      5040  4555  0 09:30 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto lightread
```

I tried including the `/usr/bin/python` in my menu entry, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when an order/launcher is executed without having a specific `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`.

I'm afraid I might be wrong, but, based on my personal experience, this is what I think is happening.

Probably it's because your `.desktop` file under the directories above do not launch the same *exact* order you launch through the terminal. Let's say your `application.desktop` file contains

> Exec=app --some_option

If you launch `app` from the terminal, it will somehow relate it to the `application.desktop` file, but it will just use the small sized icon, instead of chosing the proper one for the situation.

Nontheless, I don't know how to properly solve it. Modifying the `.desktop` file may work, but I'm not sure at all.